# Throwing Custom Exceptions in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to throw a custom exception but no exception is thrown in spock test.

```
Class A{
   static class B extends Exception{

   }
   public Object getObject() throws B{
       if(condition 1){}
       else if(condition 2){}
       else if(condition 3){ throw new A.B()}

   }
}
```

But no exception is thrown when condition matches
I am using gradle to setup build environment and Spring framework

Comment: Your first `else if(condition){}` throws nothing.  Why do you have two branches with the same condition?

Comment: after the edit:  Condition 3 can never be met then...  Or something else in the code you're not showing us is subverting it...

Comment: This code is just a representation, there are certain variables that correspond to some value. That value is being checked and subsequent action is being taken. condition 3 is being met but no exception is thrown test case

Comment: Can't be happening. That's not how code works.  Either your exception is being caught by something calling the above class, or the condition isn't being met

Comment: That's easily verified:
    `Class A {
       static class B extends Exception { }
       public Object getObject() throws B {
           throw new A.B()
       }
    }`
If this works, the problem lies within the if/else statements.

Comment: These conditions are relying on a function callback. I've mocked test specification to meet the third condition, when i debug it enters the code block.

Comment: What mocking framework are you using? What does your test code look like?